# Product.attribute.js file - Object doesn't support 'findIndex'

Tags: javascript, jquery, bigcommerce

My product pages are styled and functioning fine in every browser except IE. When I go to IE I have JS that is literally the same as code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9gjtw/), only replaced the Lorem Ipsum with descriptive text about the product.

It functions in JSfiddle and it functions in every other browser, but when I go to IE and look in the console I am seeing this error:

`Object doesn't support property or method 'findIndex'` in the product.attributes.js file.

I'm assuming that this error is causing all my JS after it to halt and not run my simple jQuery tabs.

Now BigCommerce doesn't have direct access where I can make edits in this file as its in the template and framework. Its ONLY happening with products that have options and are displayed in a Pick List with Photos. I can't change all of my products to display differently and I'm not sure how I can access this code.

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 doesn't support the `findIndex` method.  If you need to support IE, you'll need to use a polyfill.  Per MDN, the polyfill [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) should work just fine.

If you don't have access to edit them files directly, you should be able to copy/paste the polyfill and enter it in the "header scripts" section in admin, in the "themes" area.